# nunit3 issue with coreapp2.0

Tags: nunit, asp.net-core-2.0

I try to run nunit test with cake (and manually). I have the following .csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net40' and '$(TargetFramework)' != 'net45'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I execute the following command:
    nunit3-console.exe myDLL.Test.dll

Same issue with the following cake script

```
var settings = new NUnit3Settings();
NUnit3(testAssembly.ToString(), settings);
```

I have the following stacktrace

```
1) Error :
NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException : The NUnit 3 driver cannot support this test assembly. Use a platform specific runner.
  ----> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Le type 'NUnit.Framework.Api.FrameworkController' dans l'assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' n'est pas marqué comme sérialisable.
--NUnitEngineException
The NUnit 3 driver cannot support this test assembly. Use a platform specific runner.

Server stack trace:
   à NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.Load(String testAssemblyPath, IDictionary`2 settings)
   à NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadDriver(IFrameworkDriver driver, String testFile, TestPackage subPackage)
   à NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadPackage()
   à NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.EnsurePackageIsLoaded()
   à NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
   à System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   à System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
```

How can I resolve it ? Thanks

Comment: What kind of project do you want to run? .NET Core projects in general should be executed via `dotnet test`.

Comment: I try to run net40;net45;netcoreapp2.0 project. net40 and net45 are good but I would like use the same script with netcoreapp2.0 configuration.

Comment: A multitargeting project can of course be executed by `dotnet test`. My example https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/Tests/CSharpCore/Tests.NetStandard.csproj